# cant concatenate aws_api_gateway_integration uri terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have a lambda alias tied to value `dev`. From the AWS API Gateway UI, I can set the lambda function and alias or version. `function-arn:alias` or `function-arn:version`.

However, if I try to concatenate the value for uri param, I get the following error:

**Error updating API Gateway Integration: BadRequestException: Integrations of type 'AWS_PROXY' currently only supports Lambda function and Firehose stream invocations.**

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "foo_bar" {
  rest_api_id             = xxx
  resource_id             = xxx
  http_method             = xxx
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = "${var.lambdaxyz_lambda_arn}:${var.environment}"
}
```

Comment: Where is the Lambda function defined?

Comment: @MarkoE separate module. I've just abstracted that away from this question. I pass in the invoke arn as a variable.

Comment: You need an ivoke ARN not function ARN.